# initwithnibname pass variable to next view

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have one view where I read json data. and extract keys from it.

in - (void)viewDidLoad {
I do the following:

```
hotellat = [rows4 valueForKey:@"H_LAT"];
hotellon = [rows4 valueForKey:@"H_LON"];
```

Then I perform a push after the viewDidLoad like below:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"hotellat: %@",hotellat);
    MapTutorialViewController *controller = [[MapTutorialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapTutorialViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    controller.LAT = hotellat;
    controller.LON = hotellon;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
```

NSlog in this section shows that hotellat is null, but when I write the nslog in the viewDidload, there is a value. What is it that I need to do to get this variable to pass to next view? also this is a string, and I think I need to convert it to integer so I can assign it to the latitude in map view?

I also @synthesize hotellat, hotellon; in the controller and have the following in the .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *hotellat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *hotellon;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

though you are using retained variables but retain message is not being sent to the values by this assignment:

```
hotellat = [rows4 valueForKey:@"H_LAT"];
hotellon = [rows4 valueForKey:@"H_LON"];
```

use:

```
self.hotellat = [rows4 valueForKey:@"H_LAT"];
self.hotellon = [rows4 valueForKey:@"H_LON"];
```

this way the retain message will be passed to the value and it will be ensured that it stays there until you release it explicitly.

later on you can release the values:
lets say after: `[controller release];`

```
[hotellat release];
[hotellon release];
```

Comment: for using them in mapview, you need to convert NSString to float first, CGFloat lat = [hotellat floatValue];

Comment: Thanks again. I did manage to pass the variables to next view. but converting them to float didn't work:
    CGFloat Nlat = [hotellat floatValue];
    CGFloat Nlon = [hotellon floatValue];
    NSLog(@"Lat: %@",Nlat);
    NSLog(@"Lon: %@",Nlon);
At this point simulator crashes and I see this in the logs: 
iProject[15057:11603] Lat: (null)
2011-12-17 18:49:35.753 iProject[15057:11603] Lon: (null)
2011-12-17 18:49:35.754 iProject[15057:11603] -[__NSArrayI floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d6f360

Comment: we use %f formatter to print float values..change your log to:  NSLog(@"Lat: %f",Nlat);

Comment: you need to strengthen your basics otherwise you will stuck at each step of coding..!!

Comment: Okay I used this format. It crashed again. But this time log didn't show null but showed this: Lat: 0.000000   However the string before it was converted to float was 34.3456

Comment: You're right about strengthening the basics. Problem is in this part of the world its not possible to get a book. So I am waiting for february when I will travel to a bigger country where I will have access to relevant publications.

Comment: till the time you can go through apple's own book on objective-c with this link: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/objc.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link Samfisher